# After adding an item from one listbox to another counter won't change

Tags: c#

I'm trying to select an item from listbox unique colors and add it to listbox Things. I don't want to remove the item lbxUniqueColors. Right now listbox Things has 9 items but when I run my program to add a color to lbxThings the counter doesn't change it stays as 9. Heres my Code so far

Here I add the colors to lbxThings and add the counter and add the distinct colors to lbxUniqueColors:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myList =
            new List<string> { "red", "blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "yellow"
            ,"purple","violet","orange" };
        lbxThings.Items.AddRange(myList.ToArray());

        lblCounter.Text = $"Number of Things = {lbxThings.Items.Count}";

        var UniqueItems =
            (from item in myList select item).Distinct();
        lbxUniqueColors.Items.AddRange(UniqueItems.ToArray());
        lblUniqueColors.Text = $"Number of Unique Things = {lbxUniqueColors.Items.Count}";
     }
```

Here I add the label for my lbxUniqueColors listbox:

```
    private void lbxUniqueColors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblPickedColor.Text =
            $"You picked {lbxUniqueColors.SelectedItem}";

      }
```

And here is where I add the button to add the color from unique colors to lbxThings:

```
    private void bttnADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbxThings.Items.Add(lbxUniqueColors.SelectedItem);
        lblCounter.Text = $"Number of Things = {lbxThings.Items.Count}";

    }
```

Comment: Visual Studio includes an **[AWESOME Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** which makes figuring these things out very easy.  In return you learn how code really works.

Comment: My guess is your xaml is not set up properly. Can you post the xaml code? Or perhaps this is winforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code perfectly works as you described. Counter gets incremented once you select the color from the drop down and then press the button. However, it will be a always a good idea to safeguard it against null value.

```
 private void bttnADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbxUniqueColors.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            lbxThings.Items.Add(lbxUniqueColors.SelectedItem);
            lblCounter.Text = $"Number of Things = {lbxThings.Items.Count}";
        }
    }
```

[image]